# SY-INDEX as a counter for WHILE loop gives weird numbers

Tags: loops, counter, abap

I wrote a program to count the number of each vowel in a string character.

```
    DATA: v_nom(10)  TYPE c VALUE 'christian',
          vowels     TYPE string,
          lenght     TYPE i,
          char       TYPE c,
          occurences TYPE i,
          index      TYPE i.
    
    vowels ='aeiouy'.
    lenght =  strlen( vowels ).
    
    index = sy-index.
    
    WRITE index.
    
    WHILE index < lenght.
    
      char = vowels+index.
    
      FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF char IN v_nom MATCH COUNT occurences.
    
    
      ADD 1 TO index.
    
      IF occurences = 0.
    
      ELSE.
    
     write:/ char, 'appears',/ occurences, 'times'.
    
      ENDIF.
    ENDWHILE.
```

It works fine... but at first I try do it by using directly `sy-index` without assigning it to a variable, an the problem when I run the debug I saw that `sy-index` starts at the position 1, not 0.

Using a variable or using directly the system variable should work the same?

```
DATA: v_nom(10)  TYPE c VALUE 'christian',
      vowels     TYPE string,
      lenght     TYPE i,
      char       TYPE c,
      occurences TYPE i.

vowels ='aeiouy'.
lenght =  strlen( vowels ).


WHILE sy-index < lenght.

  char = vowels+sy-index.

  FIND ALL OCCURRENCES OF char IN v_nom MATCH COUNT occurences.
  ADD 1 TO index.

  IF occurences = 0.

  ELSE.

 write:/ char, 'appears',/ occurences, 'times'.

  ENDIF.
ENDWHILE.
```

`Sy-index` starts at pos 1 not 0, by the letter 'e' not with the first one which is 'a'....

Can someone tell me where I make a mistake....

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

| Name | Type | Length | Content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sy-index | i | - | Loop index. In DO and WHILE loops, contains the number of previous loop passes, including the current pass. |

> Within the statement block, the system field sy-index contains the number of previous loop passes, including the current pass.

[Documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_756_index_htm/7.56/en-US/index.htm).

Now in your example you assign `sy-index` before you reach the loop. Hence it will have it's initial value, which is `0` for type `i`.
If you use it within the loop, the first iteration will have `1` (number of previous loop passes, including the current pass).
And yes, ABAP is a 1-based language. The first line of an internal table is also `lt_sflight[ 1 ]`, not `lt_sflight[ 0 ]`.

Comment: THanks for the answer, that's mean i can't use sy-index, in my 2nd example ?

Comment: You can, you keep in mind it's always starting at 1. So you'd have to substract one whenever you use it. So `WHILE sy-index < lenght + 1` and `DATA(offset) = sy-index - 1. char = vowels+offset(1)`

Comment: Or you'd declare a table of character with the vowels and iterate over this instead. Similar to arrays in other languages. `LOOP AT vowels REFERENCE INTO(vowel).`

Comment: Thanks you for your insights and help.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this can be solved way easier with [`count_any_of`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abencount_functions.htm):

```
DATA(occurences) = count_any_of( 
  val = v_nom
  sub = 'aeiouy'
).
```

Answer (score 0):

The point that threw you into confusion is the [offset substring access](https://eduardocopat.github.io/abap-docs/7.54/abenoffset_length/).
In the help this thing is expressed rather ambiguous but the rule of thumb is this:

offset counter `vowels+n` always starts **from 0 (zero)** whilst `sy-index` **from 1 (one)**.

This fact caused the disrepancy you described here:

> Sy-index starts at pos 1 not 0, by the letter 'e' not with the first one which is 'a'....